# Getting an error message for updates

Tags: updates

I am getting an error message

```
E:Type' -2014-07-10' is not known on line 1 in source list/etc/apt/sources.list d/playonlinux.list.
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? It won't let me report this error or anything. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list`?